# how to set popup window at the bottom of all screen size in Android?

Tags: android

I creating  camerapopup.xml in my application . I want to display this pop up window at the bottom of screen for all screen size . I have tried to creating different layout folders (layout-large , layout-small,layoutxlarge etc )but does not work at all How to set the popup window for all screen size at the bottom .Can someone help me how to work with that.Thanks in advanced .

Here is my xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Take Photo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Camera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
            android:text="Camera"
            android:textColor="#3A86CF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:textColor="#3A86CF" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelCamera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#3A86CF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Activity code

```
imgProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.setWidth(720);
                popupWindow.setHeight(350);
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

                Button btnCamera = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_Camera);
                Button btnGallery = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_Gallery);
                Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCamera);
}
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Use this in all your java file 

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ppopup_element,
                null);

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        dialog.setView(dialogLayout, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = dialog.getWindow()
                .getAttributes();
        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;


          Button btnCamera = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_Camera);
            Button btnGallery = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_Gallery);
            Button btnDismiss = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelCamera);


        builder.setView(dialogLayout);

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply . I tried your code and its working , but some little problem can you tell me how to set width  of AlertDialog.Builder as fill parent .

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
   Window window = dialog.getWindow();
   lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

   lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
   lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
   lp.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM;
   window.setAttributes(lp);